# Import point cloud into PostgreSQL/ pdal pipeline fails

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ubuntu, boundless-suite, lidar

I have a point cloud dataset that I would like to upload to my postgres/postgis database.

I followed [this tutorial](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-lidar/) and I could install everything without problems (on ubuntu 14.04. On ubuntu 12.04 it did not work [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151002/opengeo-lidar-example-unable-to-use-pdal)), but I have issues to upload the point cloud into my database.

In the tutorial there are some commands to check the lidar metadata. This one is not working in my case:  `pdal info --input merged.laz --metadata --xml`

it says:

> Usage error: option '--xml' did not split correctly. Is it in the form
>   --readers.las.option=foo?

pdal generate error when I try to upload the lidar data to the database: `pdal pipeline --input laz2pg.xml`

> PDAL: Couldn't create reader stage of type 'drivers.las.reader'.

The content of my pipeline xml file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pipeline version="1.0">
  <Writer type="drivers.pgpointcloud.writer">
    <Option name="connection">dbname='lidar' user='postgres' host='localhost' port='5432' password='Alibaba22'</Option>
    <Option name="table">test</Option>
    <Option name="srid">27000</Option>
    <Filter type="filters.chipper">
      <Option name="capacity">400</Option>
      <Filter type="filters.cache">
        <Reader type="drivers.las.reader">
          <Option name="filename">merged.laz</Option>
          <Option name="spatialreference">EPSG:27000</Option>
        </Reader>
      </Filter>
    </Filter>
  </Writer>
</Pipeline>
```

I went trough on this tutorial two times a couple of months ago and it worked, but I have no clue what is wrong now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Reader` and `Writer` types are incorrect. They should be `readers.las` and `writers.pgpointcloud`, respectively. The name change happened here: https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/commit/b7cde7e1fb13f28db1de7797dbb31392db1f7dfc.

You can run `pdal --drivers` to get a complete list of drivers supported on your system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will be on holidays for two weeks, but I will check it as soon as I'm back.